# Use Header Files without including in Source files

Tags: c++, makefile

I am porting a existing borland c++ source into gcc Compatible . I am using make to compile the source. In one of file in borland source , he is using a defines from different header file , without including that header file in that particular .h file . When i am trying to compile the same , i am getting error saying undefined . So how can we access a define variable which is defined in different   header file without including it , is there any dependency option needed to be given in makefile ?

Comment: In short, you can't in any portable way. You must include the declarations you need.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add define into your makefile. For ex. `CPPFLAGS = -DMY_DEFINE_TO_USE`. This is same as compiling gcc with `-D` option